# Degeneracy and Uniqueness in General LP

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

This is about problem 4.12 from Bertsimas & Tsitsiklis's *Introduction to Linear Optimization* à la page 190. The problem is repeated below (bold is from [errata](http://athenasc.com/linopt-errata.pdf)).

> Consider a general linear programming problem and suppose that we have a non-degenerate basic feasible solution to the primal **in which all free variables are nonzero**. Show that the complementary slackness conditions lead to a system of equations for the dual vector that has a unique solution.

From my understanding, a general LP primal-dual pair is as follows.

\begin{equation*}
   \begin{array}{cc}
    \begin{array}{rll}
     \text{minimize} & \textbf{c}^\top\textbf{x}&\\
     \text{subject to} & \textbf{a}_i^\top\textbf{x}\geqslant b_i,&i\in M_1\\
           & \textbf{a}_i^\top\textbf{x}\leqslant b_i,&i\in M_2\\
           & \textbf{a}_i^\top\textbf{x}= b_i,&i\in M_3\\
           & x_j\geqslant 0,&j\in N_1\\
           & x_j\leqslant 0,&j\in N_2\\
           & x_j~\text{free},&j\in N_3\\
    \end{array}
    &
    \begin{array}{rll}
     \text{maximize} & \textbf{p}^\top\textbf{b}\\
     \text{subject to} & p_i\geqslant 0,&i\in M_1\\
           & p_i\leqslant 0,&i\in M_2\\
           & p_i~\text{free},&i\in M_3\\
           & \textbf{p}^\top\textbf{A}_j\leqslant c_j,&j\in N_1\\
           & \textbf{p}^\top\textbf{A}_j\geqslant c_j,&j\in N_2\\
           & \textbf{p}^\top\textbf{A}_j= c_j,&j\in N_3\\
    \end{array}
    \\
   \end{array}
  \end{equation*}

A basic feasible solution $\mathbf{x}^*$ would imply that at such a point, there are exactly $n$ linearly independent active constraints. This does not say that $|M_3|=n$. There could be non-free variables that are $0$. However, [this](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/HW5solution.pdf) UCBerkeley solution claims so and the professor marked it correct. Could anyone explain why $|M_3|=n$ and why there cannot be any $x_i=0$ in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but in the solution that you linked the key step is the use of the complementary slackness conditions in the paragraph following the one you quoted which guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: @ericf, thanks for the quick response. Here is my clarification. The problem, as I understand it, wants us to show that there are $n$ linearly independent equations $c_j=\mathbf{p}'\mathbf{A}_j$ so that you can solve for a unique $\mathbf{p}$. Since this term only appears in the complementary slackness condition for the variables $x_j$, we have to show that all the $x_j$ are nonzero. This in turn replies on the claim that none of the "$n$ linearly independent active constraints" satisfied by the basic feasible solution is a sign constraint. The solution did so with $|M_3|=n$. Is that true?

Comment: I think the linked solution is wrong. Consider the LP in normal form $Ax=b, x\geq 0$ where $|M_3|<n$ (the usual case). In this setting BFS's can exist. (Also, since there a no free variables none of them are 0.)

Comment: @ericf both the linked solution and your comment are wrong (your comment is wrong because a bfs requires $n$ equality constraints (in normal form), with $n$ the dimension of $x$). Just put the problem in the question in normal form and re-read the given solution.

Comment: I still think my answer is correct but perhaps I missing something. Either way the following link provides a nice clean discussion of the topic

Comment: Oops, here's the link https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~robi/teaching/2012a-AdvancedAlgorithms/Lecture1.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjHiI382I3eAhX7HzQIHVWUBfYQFjAAegQIABAB&usg=AOvVaw1Thw9yiZE1pQLgMwzSzMzw

Answer (score 1):

The solution that you have linked is wrong. Notice that the book you are using explicitly gives a definition of what a general optimization problem looks like on page 42:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll}
  \text{minimize}   \quad & \mathbf{c}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}\\
  \text{subject to} \quad & \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{b}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

To answer your second question, we have $x_i \neq 0$ for all indices of $x$ (and not only for some subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$).

You can find a correct solution to this exercise [here](https://math.solverer.com/library/dimitris_bertsimas/introduction_to_linear_optimization/exercise_4-12?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link).